# I need help setting up a new log file

Tags: php, function, logging

I can successfully tail a message log that my web developer friend setup.  Now I have another PHP script that I need to create a log for to help troubleshoot a problem.  I copied the code my friend came up with and put it into my new PHP file:

```
function log_message($message, $type) {

    $date = date('m/d/Y h:i:s a', time());
    $message = "$date - $type - $message \n";
    error_log($message, 3, '/var/log/router');}
```

Then in various places throughout my code I added lines similar to the following:

```
log_message("Email to $recipient: was successfully sent.", $info);
```

I duplicated a log file in /var/log, renamed the file to router and then deleted the existing log information that was in it so that its empty.  This log file code works great on the PHP page that my friend created, but I can't get it to work on the page I am troubleshooting.

In the past I simply stored debugging messages in the session, but I'm branching out and trying to make use of log files.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is because of the escaping?

```
function log_message($message, $type) {
    $date = date('m/d/Y h:i:s a', time());
    $message = $date . " - " . $type . " - " . $message . "\n";
    error_log($message, 3, '/var/log/router');
}
```

Does that work? Hope to help

Comment: But this exact same code works on another PHP page. So the problem can't be the escaping. Maybe the path is not correct?  How can I find the full correct path to /var/log/ no matter what the location is of the PHP file that is being executed?